# UIImagePicker Changing my Background?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller, didreceivememorywarning

I am opening an image picker, camera style, as a modalviewcontroller.  If I open the image picker, then cancel, the previous view comes back fine.

If I open the image picker, take a picture, then go back and cancel, the background to my previous view is missing and I can see through to the main window.  Does anyone know how this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're getting a low memory warning and your view is getting released since it's currently hidden.  Set a breakpoint on didRecieveMemoryWarning...

Comment: Break Point got hit!  Man, I was completely lost.  Thanks so much, may you one day find your special breakpoint and settle down.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is that you're releasing (or rather not retaining) your views properly.  That should not happen because of the way that the modalviewcontroller, but I guess it might be possible that autoreleased views might get dumped when the modalview come in. See if you are doing any retain or release stuff in your code (including property creation). Also see if you can't hit any breakpoints within the functions of the view controller you hope to go back to. If you can hit them, try to reinitialize the view. If not, hit the documentation:[Using modalViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingModelViewControllers/PresentingModelViewControllers.html) or sample code.